# why PPO performs better than TRPO?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proximal-policy-optimization, trust-region-policy-optimization

what is the logistic behind why PPO performs better than TRPO(at least in the PPO's paper results)?
When I read both papers, it seems like PPO is just simpler version of TRPO, that it does not run optimization to find optimal next policy but just clips policy update difference. In that sense, shouldn't TRPO perform better regarding sample efficiency/performance improvement??

Below image is from PPO paper, which shows that PPO performs better than TRPO.
[image: performance comparison figure that PPO performs better than TRPO]

Comment: there are no specific answer to this question, however if you read the TRPO paper, you'll realize that in order to implement their loss, they had to rely on many approximations